# php accessing $_GET[] or $_POST[] from class

Tags: php

I have an image loaderscript I am working with that I did not write. I need to change the directory that it saves images in. The code where the file directory is save is in a class. I have never worked with classes before and the regular `$_GET[]` or Post calls do not seem to work inside a function or the package code.

**My question is how do I call a `$_GET[]` from a function within a class?**

Here is some of the code:

```
class UploadHandler
{

    protected $options;


    protected $image_objects = array();


    function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {

       ///This code will work because its in the function
       $folderName = "productImages";


       // This code below does not work
     $folderName = $_GET['folderChoice'];


        $this->options = array(
            'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/',
            'upload_dir' => 

       /// Below are the two lines in need the var to go to.
       dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/'.$folderName.'/',
       'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.$folderName.'/',


            /// DELETED CODE
            ),

     //// More deleted code
```

Comment: its `$_GET` not `$_Get`

Comment: *This code below does not work* -- what does it mean?

Comment: it means it is not seeing the call to the var in the url. I can't get the GET to echo out in the function from a call. The code you posted won't work in a package for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

> The variable name is case-sensitive.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

> ```
> Superglobals — Superglobals are built-in variables that are always available in all scopes
> ...
> $_GET — HTTP GET variables
> $_POST — HTTP POST variables
> ...
> ```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

So, you have to rename your $_Get and $_Post to $_GET and $_POST

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can call `$_GET` inside the function, there's nothing wrong with that.

As soon as you'll create an object, the constructor will be called and the things will work as expected-

```
$handler = new UploadHandler(null, true, null);
```

Answer (score -3):

I always thought the directives were universally global, but with php anything out of scope of your function (I thought aside from the language globals, but maybe I'm wrong), you need to import them as globals.

```
global $_GET;
```

But I'll reiterate setting I didn't think this was necessary with language globals...

Comment: I think you need to read the definition of superglobals http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php